# How large would $n$ need to be to ensure that $P(0.39\leq \overline{Y} \leq 0.41) ≥0.95$?

Tags: probability, statistics

$Y_i$, $i = 1,\ldots,n$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with $p = 0.4$. Let $\overline{Y}$ denote the sample mean. How large would $n$ need to be to ensure that $P(0.39\leq \overline{Y} \leq 0.41) ≥0.95$?

I know the mean for a Bernoulli variable is just $np$ and the variance is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$.

Answer (score 1):

$n$ times the sample mean is the sum of your $n$ random variables, which is binomial with parameters $n$ and $p=0.4$.  For large $n$ this can be approximated using the Central Limit Theorem, but if you want the
actual best $n$ I think you'll need guess-and-check with the exact formula.